# How to replicate this API methology (class + typedef)

Tags: c++

I am working with a proprietary library (*.lib) without access to all the code.
I am creating my own library to extend this proprietary library maintaining the same methodology (this is my question).

The proprietary library is used like this

```
uifcColor_ptr myColor = uifcColor::Create(255, 255, 255);
int red = myColor->GetRed();
```

Where in some h file i can see:

```
class uifcColor : virtual public xobject
{
    xdeclare (uifcColor)

protected:
    virtual ~uifcColor ()
    {
    }

public:
    xint                GetRed ();
    void                SetRed (xint value);
    static uifcColor_ptr Create (xint red, xint green, xint blue);

private:
    xint                mRed;
    xint                mGreen;
    xint                mBlue;
};
```

and

```
typedef xrchandle<uifcColor> uifcColor_ptr;
```

I cannot understand how to create and use a similar typedef.
Can someone fill the blanks and help me to understand the methodology behind this code?

Edit (as requested)

```
template <class xobject_child>
class xrchandle : public xrcbasehandle <xobject_child>
{
public:
    inline xrchandle ();
# if OSAPI == OSAPI_WIN32
    inline xrchandle (int in_obj);
# endif
    inline xrchandle (xobject_child *in_obj);
    inline xrchandle (const xrchandle<xobject_child> &copy);
    inline xrchandle (const xrcunihandle<xobject_child> &copy);
    inline ~xrchandle ();
    inline  operator xobject_child * () const;
    inline xrchandle<xobject_child>     &operator= (xobject_child *in_obj);
    inline xrchandle<xobject_child>     &operator=
                                    (const xrchandle<xobject_child> &copy);
# ifdef PTC_CXX11_RVALUE_REFERENCES
    inline xrchandle (xrchandle<xobject_child> &&copy);
    inline xrchandle<xobject_child> &operator=(xrchandle<xobject_child> &&copy);
# endif
private:
    inline void                         attach (xobject_child *in_obj);
    inline void                         release ();
    inline void                         set (xobject_child *in_obj);
};
```

Comment: Please include the definition of:  `xrchandle` in the question

Comment: Ok, it looks like they are using template to create a.... template of a class.
If you do not fully understand what templates are, I recomend you [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-hZkUa9mIs). And they are using typedef to call ```uifcColor_ptr``` instead of ```xrchandle<uifcColor>```.

```xrchandle<uifcColor>``` is the way to call your template ```template <class xobject_child>``` with ```class xobject_child``` being equal to ```uifcColor```.
It looks like pretty basic usage of templates in C++ so I highly recomend watching that video I posted.

Comment: And in case you don't understand what typedef means.
```typedef xrchandle<uifcColor> uifcColor_ptr;``` is the way to "rename"  ```xrchandle<uifcColor>```. After typedef, you dont have to call ```xrchandle<uifcColor>```, but ```uifcColor_ptr;```. 
It works in similiar way like ```#define```. But yes, as Sam Varshavichik says, your question seems to not be proper for SO. You need to learn more about C++ features to understand the code you posted.

Comment: Thank you @MateuszBoruch. I am going to learn more about templates. I have poor experience/skills with c++. Again, thank you.

Comment: no problem :p
first step to understanding the topic is to know what you do not understand, so you know what you should learn.
I recomend you to watch more videos from a yt channel I sent. When I switched to c++ from other languages it was very helpfull.